# Какая нужна библиотека? Python. Поточный алгоритм шифрования SEAL

Tags: python

Существует ли и, если да, то в какой библиотеке алгоритм SEAL

Comment: Эта: https://github.com/Lab41/PySEAL

Comment: Как ей пользоваться? Проект пишу в jupyter notebook